# Firefox popup blocker filtering exceptions

Tags: firefox, popups

This might be a dumb question but what exactly is the filter rule format to globally allow sites? Do I need multiple entries to handle folder structure of the sites and entries to handle subdomains? Is an asterisk used for a wildcard, do I even need to use a wildcard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To globally allow a site, just add their base url:

```
example.com    Allow
```

If you just want a subdomain of a site, say their webmail client for exmaple:

```
webmail.example.com    Allow
```

You cannot specifiy a certain directory or page to allow, pop-up rules are all based on the site.

Comment: Does example.com also cover sub.example.com, sub2.example.com ?

Comment: Yes, example.com will cover ~.example.com/~ whereas sub1.example.com covers just ~.sub1.example.com/~ (~ meant to be a star, but the editor seems to eat asterisks)

Comment: @heavyd, you need to escape your asterisks: \*

Comment: It would've been nice for their website to make it clear about subdomains / implicit wild card usage.

Comment: \*.example.com does not allow sub1.example.com

Comment: Don't forget to do this for both `http` and `https` (if you want that).

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to put this filtering rule? When I tried it in Firefox settings, it doesn't allow popups on subdomain.domain.com even if I added domain.com. It also doesn't accept \* as a wildcard for subdomains. Annoying!

Answer (score 0):

This [Mozilla Support page for **Pop-up Blocker**](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Pop-up+blocker) should be useful.

Rules are simple -- like `heavyd` has already described.

---

If you want to go beyond that in `firefox`, you should install the
[**AdBlock Plus**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) and maybe [**NoScript**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) extensions.
**AdBlock Plus** will give you lots of flexibility.

Comment: It offers no information on the rule statements